# gone "on a nighttime visit" - is it a predicative or an adverbial?

Tags: idioms, prepositional-phrases

> “. . .when you're on the train home tomorrow, you're so -" 
>  But
>   what they were, they didn't find out. Hermione had turned to the
>   portrait of the Fat Lady to get back inside and found herself facing
>   an empty painting. The Fat Lady had gone **on a nighttime visit** and
>   Hermione was locked out of Gryffindor tower 
>  (Harry Potter and
>   the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is the prepositional phrase a [predicative expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression) over the Fat Lady, or an adverbial modifying the verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly either. *Go on a visit* or *go visiting* or *make a visit* are stock constructions for expressing the verb *visit*, which is transitive, without a specific direct object.

Its use here may reflect the fact that *who* the Fat Lady is visiting is unknown and irrelevant to the narrative, or it may express the notion that the Fat Lady is visiting the bathroom -- we are not well informed about the metabolism of animate portraits.